# In one project I can write a file but in the other I can't, really strange

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

In one project I managed to get the file writing with phonegap working like so:

```
$("#download").live("click", function(){
                            writeFile();
                            });

function writeFile(){

            $.get("http://www.bartdekimpe.be/anoire/index.php/admin/getGamesUserJson/34", function(result){
                  json = result;
                  removeHTMLTags();
                   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
                  });

}


function removeHTMLTags(){
            if(json){
                var strInputCode = json;
                /* 
                 This line is optional, it replaces escaped brackets with real ones, 
                 i.e. < is replaced with < and > is replaced with >
                 */ 
                strInputCode = strInputCode.replace(/(&nbsp;)*/g,"");
                strInputCode = strInputCode.replace(/&(lt|gt);/g, function (strMatch, p1){
                                                    return (p1 == "lt")? "<" : ">";
                                                    });
               // strTagStrippedText = '"';
                strTagStrippedText = strInputCode.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
                strTagStrippedText = $.trim(strTagStrippedText); // overbodige spaties weghalen
                //strTagStrippedText += '"';
            }};

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail); 
        }

        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
        }

        function gotFileWriter(writer) {
            writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                console.log("write success");
            };
            writer.write(strTagStrippedText);


            readFile();
            // contents of file now 'some sample text'
           // writer.truncate(11);
            // contents of file now 'some sample'
           // writer.seek(4);
            // contents of file still 'some sample' but file pointer is after the 'e' in 'some'
            //writer.write(" different text");
            // contents of file now 'some different text'
        }
        // Einde FILE WRITER

        function fail(error) {
            console.log(error.code);
        }
```

In the other project I do exactly the same thing, and it won't work, I created another project cause I needed to begin all over again. I do it like so:

```
$(".startNew").live("click", function(){
                            writeFile();      
                            $.mobile.changePage($("#games"));
                            krijgSpellen();


                              });

function writeFile(){
            navigator.notification.alert("write file");
            $.get("http://www.bartdekimpe.be/anoire/index.php/admin/getGamesUserJson/34", function(result){
                  json = result;
                  removeHTMLTags();
                  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
                  });


        }

        function removeHTMLTags(){
            if(json){
                var strInputCode = json;
                /* 
                 This line is optional, it replaces escaped brackets with real ones, 
                 i.e. < is replaced with < and > is replaced with >
                 */ 
                strInputCode = strInputCode.replace(/(&nbsp;)*/g,"");
                strInputCode = strInputCode.replace(/&(lt|gt);/g, function (strMatch, p1){
                                                    return (p1 == "lt")? "<" : ">";
                                                    });
                // strTagStrippedText = '"';
                strTagStrippedText = strInputCode.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
                strTagStrippedText = $.trim(strTagStrippedText); // overbodige spaties weghalen
                //strTagStrippedText += '"';
            }};


 function gotFS(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true}, gotFileEntry, fail); 
        }

        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
        }

        function gotFileWriter(writer) {
            writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                console.log("write success");
            };
            writer.write(strTagStrippedText);


            readFile();
            // contents of file now 'some sample text'
            // writer.truncate(11);
            // contents of file now 'some sample'
            // writer.seek(4);
            // contents of file still 'some sample' but file pointer is after the 'e' in 'some'
            //writer.write(" different text");
            // contents of file now 'some different text'
        }
        // Einde FILE WRITER

        function fail(error) {
            console.log(error.code);
        }
```

It won't write the file, really strange, when I do this:

```
$(".startNew").live("click", function(){
                            writeFile();      
                            $.mobile.changePage($("#games"));
                            krijgSpellen();


                              });
```

it doesn't write a file but when I do this:

```
$(".startNew").live("click", function(){
                            writeFile();      
                              });
```

It does work and it writes a file

Comment: What does "won't work" mean exactly? Do you get an error message? We can't read your screen or your mind from here, so you need to tell us. (Also, please remember that this is a free peer-support site. What's urgent to you isn't really to anyone else, and people will help as soon as they can. It's not really necessary to say things like "I really need help quick"; it just adds noise and clutter.) :)

Comment: It won't write the file, really strange, when I do this: `$(".startNew").live("click", function(){
                            writeFile();      
                            $.mobile.changePage($("#games"));
                            krijgSpellen();
                              
                              
                              });` it doesn't write a file but when I do this: `$(".startNew").live("click", function(){
                            writeFile();      
                              });`
It does work and it writes a file

Answer (score 0):

from your comment above it seems like you are generating the link with class `.startNew` dynamically, that is why it works with `live`, if you are using **jquery 1.7+** use [**`on`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or else use [**`delegate`**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) because live is [**deprecated**](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/)

```
$(function(){
 $(document).on("click",".startNew", function(){ writeFile(); });
});
```

or with delegate

```
$(function(){
     $(document).delegate(".startNew","click", function(){ writeFile(); });
    });
```

Comment: `on`doesn't work, `delegate`changes the page and downloads it but when I add `$.mobile.changePage($("#games"));` and `krijgSpellen();` to the click function it stops working

Comment: what version of jquery you are using

Comment: I'm using the latest one: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`

Comment: my bad i have edited the code the `on` should work now, as far as the addition of `$.mobile.changePage($("#games"));` and `krijgSpellen();` breaking the functionality is concerned there might be something wrong with them, `stops working` doesn't really help

Comment: I don't know what should be wrong with it because the functions do what they supposed to be doing

Comment: have you checked with the firebug for any potential javascript errors

Comment: I can't use firebug due it's phone gap and it's running on an iPhone simulator